# Does Spring Security require the use of Spring Session?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, spring-session

We are looking to externalize our sessions in memcached, but for various reasons specific to our architecture, Spring Session is not a good choice for us. We DO, however, want to utilize Spring Security to secure the application.

Do any security-related features in Spring Security REQUIRE Spring Session? Features like Concurrent Session Control or CSRF protection come to mind as features that might require Spring Session. Or, is Spring Session not required at all?

Comment: You can achieve this using configuration <http create-session="stateless">...</http>. But this is specific to Spring Security

Comment: suppose you refer the documentation on spring security [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/security.html)

Comment: @RamachandraReddy My application is stateful. Will that disable Spring Session, or session creation entirely? I need sessions.

Comment: Can you read http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session, you will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Spring Security does not depend on *Spring Session* library. I have used Spring Security in several projects and never seen a requirement of Spring Session.

Per default Spring Security uses the standard `HttpSession` in the Servlet API. The framework is highly customizable so I would say, without have tested it, that even that part could be switched out for some custom code that stores the state.